# Object detection API xml file

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have tried and follow some tutorial about object detection API. I can see that most of us using LabelImg to create XML files for label the data. But I have a question that if inside the image we don't have the object so we not label and therefore missing an XML file?.

So we should remove that image which not contained any object or we still keep that image? And if keep how we can use this if no xml file? Because I think this image may provided negative info for model and help model not miss-detect the non-object.

Comment: the tensorflow object detection api itself ignores files which doesn't  have xml files, when you convert the images and xml files to tfrecords

Comment: It's ok to keep images that do not have the object of interest, its just a case without object. We will get the xml file generated for this image as well, but only the properties of image will be present in it, object class will not be present.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply. But thing I wonder that is these images help improve anything ?